# unable to compile ndiswrapper

Tags: ndiswrapper

I'm trying to install ndiswrapper to get my wireless Netgear to work.
I did the following:

```
apt-get install ndiswrapper-source
```

Which completes successfully.

Then:

```
apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms
```

Which returns:
    Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.2) ...
    Setting up ndiswrapper-dkms (1.57-1ubuntu1) ...
    Loading new ndiswrapper-1.57 DKMS files...
    First Installation: checking all kernels...
    Building only for 3.11.0-19-generic
    Building initial module for 3.11.0-19-generic
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-19-generic (x86_64)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.57/build/make.log for more information.

When I look at /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.57/build/make.log I see:

```
Cannot find kernel build files in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic
Please give the path to kernel build directory with
the KBUILD=<path> argument to make
```

Upon closed examination the makefile expects to find:

```
$(KBUILD)/include/linux/version.h

/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/config/evm/hmac/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
```

What's going wrong? Looks like an incompatibility between the ndiswrapper and the kernel. But I'm using the latest version of both.

Update:
I downloaded
The driver compiled fine and I was able to install my driver:

```
ndiswrapper -l
bcmwlhigh6 : driver installed
device (0846:9011) present
```

However, I still have no wireless, iwconfig does not show anything.
I noticed that:

```
modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Returns nothing.

Then I did:
    dmesg|grep ndis

And voila. Seems like even though the driver compiled and installed successfully it's all broken, possibly due to the kernel mismatch or something...

```
[  495.031481] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  495.032287] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  495.295718] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[  495.295725] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[  495.295729] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:     NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[  495.295734] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMResetComplete'
[  495.295737] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMAllocatePort'
[  495.295741] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[  495.295744] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:    NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[  495.295748] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[  495.295751] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[  495.295756] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMNetPnPEvent'
[  495.295761] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[  495.295765] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMFreePort'
[  495.295768] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[  495.295772] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMPauseComplete'
[  495.295776] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[  495.295779] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisCancelTimerObject'
[  495.295783] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[  495.295786] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisSetTimerObject'
[  495.295790] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeTimerObject'
[  495.295794] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateTimerObject'
[  495.295797] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[  495.295801] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[  495.295808] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMGetBusData'
[  495.295812] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisGetSystemUpTimeEx'
[  495.295815] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[  495.295819] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[  495.295822] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[  495.295828] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[  495.295832] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[  495.295839] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[  495.295841] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBindClass'
[  495.295844] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:  WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbindClass'
[  495.295847] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[  495.295849] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'bcmwlhigh6'
[  495.296262] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh6; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  495.296300] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up downloading 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/1.59-1/ndiswrapper_1.59.orig.tar.gz

then make and make install.
After downloading the correct driver bcmn43xx64 as described in [Unable to get wireless netgear WNDA3100v2 to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446708/unable-to-get-wireless-netgear-wnda3100v2-to-work) I was able to connect to wlan.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are running Ubuntu 12.04.4 Precise. The ndiswrapper version in the repositories is 1.57. However, 12.04.4 uses the same kernel, build tools, etc. as Ubuntu 13.10. I expect you'd have better luck downloading and installing ndiswrapper 1.58 from Saucy here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ndiswrapper&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all

In order to use ndiswrapper-source, it must first be extracted and compiled. From the README:

```
less /usr/share/doc/ndiswrapper-source/README.Debian
```

> ## Building ndiswrapper kernel modules with module-assistant
>
> Please install the module-assistant package and issue the following
>   commands:-
>
> $ m-a prepare
>       $ m-a a-i ndiswrapper
>
> The above commands will prepare, compile, package and install a set of
>   ndiswrapper modules for your kernel.
>
> m-a is short for module-assistant, and a-i is short for auto-install.
>   Please see the module-assistant documentation for further details.

In Ubuntu, those commands require sudo.

Comment: I actually tried that too. I get "Bad luck, the kernel headers for the target kernel version could be found and you did not specify other valid kernel headers to use."

Comment: Also it seems like it's the same code version 1.57, just packaged differently. "Unpacking ndiswrapper-source (from .../ndiswrapper-source_1.57-1ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up ndiswrapper-source (1.57-1ubuntu1) ..."

Comment: Are you saying that if you download 1.58-2 from my link that it unpacks as 1.57?? Also, do you have linux-headers-generic installed?

Comment: Yep. that's exactly what appears to be happening.