# Unable to get wireless netgear WNDA3100v2 to work

Tags: wireless, netgear

After a long struggle I was able to successfully install the ndiswrapper and the windows driver. The driver is reported now as installed:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
bcmwlhigh6 : driver installed
    device (0846:9011) present
```

The device id matches the one from lsusb output:

```
lsusb|grep Net
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
```

But still can't connect to wireless.

```
iwconfig
  eth0      no wireless extensions.
  lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I noticed that:

```
modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Returns nothing.

Then I did:
    dmesg|grep ndis

And voila. What do those messages mean? Both my drivers and my ubuntu are x64.

```
[  495.031481] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  495.032287] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[  495.295718] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisQueueIoWorkItem'
[  495.295725] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeIoWorkItem'
[  495.295729] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:     NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSetMiniportAttributes'
[  495.295734] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMResetComplete'
[  495.295737] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMAllocatePort'
[  495.295741] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateIoWorkItem'
[  495.295744] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:    NDIS.SYS:'NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete'
[  495.295748] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMDeregisterMiniportDriver'
[  495.295751] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:   NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool'
[  495.295756] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMNetPnPEvent'
[  495.295761] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMRegisterMiniportDriver'
[  495.295765] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMFreePort'
[  495.295768] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists'
[  495.295772] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMPauseComplete'
[  495.295776] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferListPool'
[  495.295779] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisCancelTimerObject'
[  495.295783] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisOpenConfigurationEx'
[  495.295786] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisSetTimerObject'
[  495.295790] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeTimerObject'
[  495.295794] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateTimerObject'
[  495.295797] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMIndicateStatusEx'
[  495.295801] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeNetBufferList'
[  495.295808] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMGetBusData'
[  495.295812] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisGetSystemUpTimeEx'
[  495.295815] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList'
[  495.295819] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMdl'
[  495.295822] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisFreeMdl'
[  495.295828] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisMOidRequestComplete'
[  495.295832] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS:'NdisAllocateMemoryWithTagPriority'
[  495.295839] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBind'
[  495.295841] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionBindClass'
[  495.295844] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol:  WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbindClass'
[  495.295847] ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS:'WdfVersionUnbind'
[  495.295849] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'bcmwlhigh6'
[  495.296262] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver bcmwlhigh6; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  495.296300] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that bcmwlhigh6 is correct for your device. I suggest you try the files from post #6 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2052594

Comment: Actually I did try this one as well last night. Even though it looked promising (no errors in syslog) iwconfig still showed nothing. I rebooted the machine this morning and... there is my wlan0! bcmn43xx64 is the driver that works though I've no idea where it came from, big thanks to that person who put it out there because my driver CD only included bcmwlhigh6.