# Netgear wnda3100v2 taking forever to establish wi-fi connection

Tags: wireless, connection, netgear

I got my Netgear N600 WNDA3100v2 set up as described here:
[Unable to get wireless netgear WNDA3100v2 to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446708/unable-to-get-wireless-netgear-wnda3100v2-to-work)

However, I've been having problems establishing the wi-fi connection.
Basically it takes anywhere between 2 to 10 minutes to to connect after a reboot. Things seem smooth once the connection gets established.
Here is my iwconfig output.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:"qwest6144"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 00:23:75:26:66:20   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
      RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:100/100  Signal level:-28 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:77  Invalid misc:40921   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe drivers for your issue, I used the drivers linked in this guide and don't have the issues in 14.04 you are describing: http://av3ngr.wikispaces.com/Netgear+WNDA3100v2+USB

Only issue I've ran into with this config is a strange issue with wireless related to dual booting, not sure if you are dual booting. If I warm reboot from Windows to Ubuntu. Wireless works no issues. Once in Ubuntu and warm reboot into Windows, wireless blinks amber and blue, and doesn't recognize in Windows. I have to re-seat the USB. It only does this during a warm reboot from Ubuntu to Windows, Cold boots wireless works without issues. I would imagine this is something to do with ndiswrapper, but haven't been able to pinpoint. :\

Comment: Hi and welcome to ask Ubuntu. Please take the time to review the information in the help center on how to [write effective answers](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). Your post here is a mix of comments and a new question. In order to keep the site format consistent, we avoid asking multiple questions on the same thread even if they seem related. Feel free to open a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) link on the top right of this page. Be as descriptive as possible and include any relevant information like error messages, etc