# Netgear WNDA-3100 Wifi adapter driver install

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a netgear wnda3100. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have been trying to install the drivers for it for 2 hours now.

The official documentaion says to go to **System**>**Administration**>**Drivers** but apparently that no longer exists in this version of Ubuntu.

I found something called **Additional Drivers**, but that said `No additional drivers available` - even though Ubuntu is supposed to come with the broadcom sta drivers. Maybe this is the wrong place to look for it?

I tried downloading the drivers on Windows but it said they needed to be compiled to be used and I have no clue how to do that. Can someone please help me? I am so frustrated.

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0461:4d42 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0151 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device (Multicard Reader)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic Keyboard 200
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I was using this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers

I did it. Thank you very much chili5555!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the official documentation you've been following? Judging by what you said, it sounds like those instructions are for a previous version of Ubuntu - back when the default Desktop Environment was GNOME.

Comment: Depending on the version, it needs to be installed with ndiswrapper. Please edit your question to add the result of: lsusb Thanks.

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/446708/unable-to-get-wireless-netgear-wnda3100v2-to-work