# How do I get my computer connected to a wireless network using my Netgear WNDA3100v2?

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet

I am very new to Linux in general, so this could be quite frustrating to all the more experienced users out there. I currently have an Ethernet connection to my router and I would like to be able to connect to my wifi using the mentioned wifi adapter. I have perused the internet attempting multiple solutions and failing at each, for approximately 5 hours. I am quite frustrated. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/446708/unable-to-get-wireless-netgear-wnda3100v2-to-work

Comment: I have a very similar output to that user. However the files i used were yours chili. I had already found your thread. ("sudo ndiswrapper -l") returns "bcmn43xx64 : driver installed (next line) device (0846: 9011) present.

Comment: ("lsusb|grep Net") returns "Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0846: 9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]".  ("iw config") returns "lo   no wireless extensions    enp3s0      no wireless extensions."@chili555

Comment: Are there any clues in: `dmesg | grep ndis` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25480325/

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to pack it up for today. I can't hog the ethernet cable for so long. Feel free to leave your analysis of the link in these comments and hopefully we can solve this problem together tomorrow, in approximately 16 hours. @chili555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How do I get my computer connected...using my Netgear WNDA3100v2"

The answer is that you probably cannot.

ndiswrapper the package hasn't been updated regularly and not at all for some ten months. Questions on their own help forum go unanswered: https://sourceforge.net/p/ndiswrapper/discussion/323167/thread/dd8b33b1/

As well, the Windows XP inf and sys files are also quite old, dating to 2009:

```
ndiswrapper: driver bcmn43xx64 (,08/26/2009, 5.10.79.30) loaded
```

While there are a few threads reporting success, they are all with older kernel versions, 3.13-xx or so. While it is tempting to simply install an older Ubuntu version, these versions are, or will be soon, End-of-Life and will no longer receive any updates inluding critical security updates. As well, there is no guarantee that the specific Ubuntu version you pick will actually work properly with ndiswrapper.

On the other hand, for a few dollars, you could buy a fully supported, plug in and connect USB wireless. These sites will be helpful in selecting one: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309068 and: https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/wireless-networking-gnulinux

I regret that I do not have better news.

Comment: That might be the best news there is, maybe I just needed someone to tell me that my adapter isn't going to work for what I want it to. Thank you so much. Hopefully I can get one of these up at a store rather than order it online, I'd rather not wait a number of days. Anyways, Thank You extensively. I give you my heartfelt gratitude for trying to assist, and my sincere respect for your ability to deliver a concise message, but not disrespectful, on the lack of functionality of my current setup. You even gave links through which I might buy a new piece of Hardware! Chili, a god among men.